# Convergence in distribution off by one correction?

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that $\mu > 0$ is given. I know that $\mathsf{Ber}(n, \mu/n)\to \mathsf{Poi}(\mu)$ in distribution. Is it also true that $\mathsf{Ber}(n-1, \mu/n) \to \mathsf{Poi}(\mu)$? If possible, I'd like to show this using the simpler characterization of distributional convergence (ie., not the version which says something about integration of bounded continuous functions). One idea I had was to show that the total variation distance between $\mathsf{Ber}(n, \mu/n)$ and $\mathsf{Ber}(n-1, \mu/n)$ goes to zero, which would be sufficient by the triangle inequality, but I'm having trouble getting the details to work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poisson Theorem says:

> $\forall n \geq 1, X_{n,k}$ for $k=1...n,$ are independent random variables identically distributed as a $B(p_n)$ and $np_n \longrightarrow \lambda > 0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $p_n \rightarrow 0$. If so, then:

$$ S_{n,n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{n,k} \overset L \longrightarrow X = P(\lambda) \Longrightarrow B(n,p_n) \simeq P(\lambda)$$

If we change $n$ for $n-1$, the hypothesis $(n-1)p_{n-1}$ is $np_{n-1} - p_{n-1}$ and for $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $p_n \rightarrow 0$ (so $p_{n-1} \rightarrow 0)$, is $\lambda - 0 = \lambda$. So here we have the importance of limit to $\infty$.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_n\sim B(n-1,\mu/n)$ and $Y_n\sim B(n,\mu/n)$; you want to show the TV distance between the laws of $X_n$ and $Y_n$ goes like $\mu/n\to0$.  I think this is a good idea.

Here's one way to see why this is so.
Construct a coupling   $Y_n=X_n+Z_n$, where $Z_n\sim B(1,\mu/n)$ is independent of $X_n$.  Then the TV distance is bounded by $P(X_n\ne Y_n) =P(Z_n=1)=\mu/n$.  For given any set $A$, when conditioning on $Z_n$ you get (after a tiny bit of algebra) $$|P(X_n\in A) - P(Y_n\in A)|\le \frac \mu n .$$

Comment: Yep, that makes sense. I figured there would be a correction term (i.e., something like your $Z_n$ to add to $X_n$ to make it equal to $Y_n$ in distribution; thanks for giving me a direction to go here!